# Apache modrewrite htaccess problem

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a rule, that gets up to three parts, separated by a / (slash).
They represent **/app/controller/action**, but they are optional, which means **/**, **/app**, **/app/controller** work as well.

The thing is, I want another rule, before this one, which would set the default app to "frontend", and I think it should look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/$1
```

However, if I have the url **/part1** everything is ok and it is received as **/frontend/part1**. However, if the url contains a / (slash), like **/part1/part2** , I get a 500 internal error. If I remove this rule, the initial one works with **/frontend/part1/part2**, so the problem is within this rule. It seems the $1 does not accept slashes in it. Is that a known fact?

And also, I would like that this rule is not ran if the current url already starts with frontend/, I'm thinking something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^frontend(/.*)?$ frontend$1 [S=1]
```

Or could this be done more elegantly with a RewriteCond ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond $0 !^frontend/
RewriteRule .* frontend/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks!!! It seems to work.
But can you quickly explain why wasn't mine working or what's the difference between your and my solutin?
$0 means all the query, right?

Comment: Your solution is probably causing an infinite loop. But my rule excludes any match that begins with `frontend/` to be rewritten to `frontend/…`. And, yes, `$0` contains the match of the entire pattern.